# Creating a HQL query which would take each item in a collection and compare it

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have the following HQL query

```
SELECT ob FROM objectBase ob WHERE size(ob.listSC) > 0 AND ob.listSC.registrationDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```

What it is supposed to do:

1. Take all **objectBase** objects in a database where **listSC** (a collection of entities) is not **null** and **empty** (unfortunately cannot figure out how to make it ingore null values too)
2. For each item inside **listSC** check that a particular entity has a property of **registrationDate** between given dates.

But unfortunately it gives me

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [objectbase0_.id.listSC] with element property reference [registrationDate]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode$1.buildIllegalCollectionDereferenceException(DotNode.java:73)
```

Which is for a good reason I believe. The question is how to implement such behaviour anyway?
Preferably, without using **JOINs**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because ob.listSC is a collection and doesn't have property registrationDate

Comment: That's exactly the problem! The query doesn't look nice to me either, but I don't know how to re-write it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below query if you need any help let me know.

```
SELECT ob FROM objectBase ob left join ob.listSC sc WHERE size(ob.listSC) > 0 AND sc.registrationDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```

Comment: It seems to work, thank you very much! BTW, how do I also eliminate **null** values from the query of listSC, so it would only include ob.listSC which are not null? Or does `size(ob.listSC) > 0` process only objects where the collection is not null implicitly AND at least have one item?

Comment: It supports it implicitly.